# Escaping JavaScript Strings in Python

Tags: javascript, python

I have a Python script that builds some JavaScript to send down to the browser in a JSON envelope. I'd like to escape the JavaScript strings and delimit them with single quotes. I can't use `json.dumps` because it uses double quotes as delimiters like the JSON spec requires.

Is there a JavaScript String escape method in Python?

Example

```
def logIt(self, str):
    #todo: need to escape str here
    cmd = "console.log('%(text)s');" % { 'text': str}
    json.dumps({ "script": cmd })
```

So `logIt('example text')` should return something like this:

```
{
  "script": "console.log('example text');"
}
```

Comment: It seems to me that your code returns exactly what you need…

Comment: Not for `logIt('Uh oh\'')`

Comment: Why do you care about single vs double quotes?

Comment: Oh, yeah, I see now. This probably should've been mentioned in the questions…

Comment: I care because a single quote is 1/4 the size of \\\" and I have a lot to send over the wire.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`json.dumps` is that escaping function - it takes any value, and makes it a valid javascript literal.

```
def logIt(self, str):
    cmd = "console.log({0});".format(json.dumps(str))
    json.dumps({ "script": cmd })
```

Producing:

```
>>> print logIt('example text')
{ "script": "console.log(\"example text\");" }
>>> print logIt('example "quoted" text')
{ "script": "console.log(\"example \\\"quoted\\\" text\");" }
```

---

Or:

```
import string
import json
import functools

quote_swap = functools.partial(
    string.translate, table=string.maketrans('\'"', '"\'')
)

def encode_single_quoted_js_string(s):
    return quote_swap(json.dumps(quote_swap(s)))
```

Comment: Yeah, I know about json.dumps, but I want to avoid having \\\" for quotes that can be just '

Comment: @LanceFisher: But you can't avoid the `\\\"` here - the original text contained a `"`. I assume you're referring to the `\"`?

Comment: You're right, in this example it is the \". json.dumps that puts double quotes around it. Basically, I want a json.dumps() that outputs single quotes instead.

Comment: `json.dumps` would be a security risk. (If the script is inside a <script> tag in html), `json.dumps('</script>')` returns `"</script>"`.
See https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet for right escaping

Comment: @TahaJahangir: That's only an issue if you use it in a context like `print '<script>var myData = ' + json.dumps(...) + '; ... </script>'`. If the json isn't directly injected into the page, as the OP is describing in this quesion, it's fine.

Comment: Updated link for @TahaJahangir comment: https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross_Site_Scripting_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html