# Python replace "" to \" in text

Tags: python, string

I want to manipulate my text in python. I will use this text to embed as JavaScript data. I need the text in my text file to display exactly as follows. It should have the format I mention below, not only when it prints.

I have text:

`""text""`

and I want:

`\"text\"`

```
with open('phase2.2.1.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvFile: 
    writer = csv.writer(csvFile)
    for b in batches: 
        writer.writerow([b.replace('\n', '').replace('""', '\\"')])
```

Unfortunately, the above yields

```
\""text\""
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Bear in mind that if you're using the interactive shell, you'll see a big difference between `foo = "\"Hello\""; foo` and `foo = "\"Hello\""; print(foo)`.  The way values are represented doesn't always match the strings they output.

Comment: @ScottMermelstein. Thanks for letting me know. The thing is, I need to have this text recognized by valid JavaScript.

Comment: Isn't it to specific of a problem not to be upvoted twice? I don't see anyone googling that...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Escaping JavaScript Strings in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17118714/escaping-javascript-strings-in-python)

Comment: @ScottMermelstein that link is changing from double quotes to single quotes. Mine is two changing all "" occurrences to \"

Comment: If you want to replace `""` with something, why are you passing `'"'` instead of `'""'` to `replace` in the first place? Why did you expect that to do what you want?

Comment: Meanwhile: Why do you want to do this? Backslash-escaping is usually not something you do for its own sake, but something you to do, e.g., create Python (or C or JS) expressions, or quote filenames with embedded quotes for the shell, etc. And most of those things, there are better ways to do it.

Comment: @abarnert That was one of the variations I tried. See below.

Comment: @abarnert Yea, I have text I want to embed with JavaScript, so the text needs to follow the format for quotes embedded in a string.

Comment: @and1can: Put that in the question. Also, take `regex` out of the question tags—you're not using a regex, you're not asking for one, and there's no particular reason to believe the right answer should use one, so why add the tag?

Comment: Also give more information. If you're just trying to encode a string to be a valid JavaScript string literal, the best answer is to use JSON, after unicode-escaping it, or doing something else to deal with the handful of characters that are legal unescaped in JSON but not in JS source. JSON is almost a perfect subset of JavaScript, "strings with a quick&dirty fix for the only error I noticed so far" is not nearly as close a subset.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If what you're trying to generate is JSON-encoded strings, the right way to do that is to use the `json` module:

```
text = json.dumps(text)
```

If you're trying to generate actual JavaScript source code, that's still *almost* the right answer. JSON is very close to being a subset of JavaScript—a lot closer than a quick&dirty fix for one error you happen to have noticed so far is going to be.

If you actually want to generate correct JS code for any possible string, you have to deal with the corner cases where JSON is not quite a subset of JS. But nobody ever does (it took years before anyone even noticed the difference in the specs).

Answer (score 6):

I would suggest:

```
.replace('""', '\\"')
```

And it really works, see:

```
In [8]: x = '""text""'

In [9]: print(x.replace('""', '\\"'))
\"text\"
```

Comment: What you posted makes complete sense to me. This is why I am bewildered why the text still looks like ""text""

Comment: thanks for your help. I think our difference is that your print displays what I desire to be displayed on my text file. I need the text to be \"text\" in the text file. Sorry for being so specific. This is life when I have to conform to the JavaScript string format to embed text.

Comment: So instead of printing, you f.write or whatever is your output methd, should not be any difference.